# How to declare Services while overridding a Bundle in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

I'm extending a Symfony2 Bundle (FosUserBundle). In my extending bundle, I would like to declare some new services, but despite of my correct `DependencyInjection/SomethingExtension.php` and `services.yml` the services are not accessible.

The extension is not called, thus the `services.yml` is not loaded.

Does anybody knows how to achieve a such service declaration?

Comment: do you follow the extension naming conventions? E.g. a `AcmeUserExtension` class when your bundle is called `AcmeUserBundle`?

Comment: Yes, the naming is correct.

Comment: Are you sure that SomethingExtension.php loads yml file? There is a XML services file loaded by default

Comment: Yes, this has been checked too.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have enabled your bundle in AppKernal.php. Hope you did it :)

Next,

> you'll need to create a new "Extension" class, which will handle the
>   process. This class should live in the DependencyInjection directory
>   of your bundle and its name should be constructed by replacing the
>   Bundle suffix of the Bundle class name with Extension. For example,
>   the Extension class of AcmeHelloBundle would be called
>   AcmeHelloExtension

SRC: [Doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html#creating-an-extension-class)
So, it should look like

```
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $configuration = new Configuration();
    $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

    $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
    $loader->load('services.yml');
}
```

Finally, debug whether services are loaded or not with this command line tool.

> The command line `php app/console container:debug` shows the list of
>   services.

Comment: for the first point, yes, the Bundle is loaded and running. Everything seems to be done correctly but nothing shows up in "container:debug"

Answer (score 0):

You can ensure that the extension class is being called (regardless of any naming issues) by overriding getContainerExtension in your Bundle code.

```
namespace Cerad\Bundle\AccountBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

use Cerad\Bundle\AccountBundle\DependencyInjection\AccountExtension;

class CeradAccountBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function getContainerExtension()
    {
        return new AccountExtension();
    }
}
```